# How do I include the array name in my Json response?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

In my controller I have the following code to generate a Json response whenever a particular URL is hit.

```
    public JsonResult LatLng()
    {
        var zones = zoneRepository.GetCoordinates().ToList();

        return Json(zones, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

The output looks like this.

```
[{"Zip_Code":1001,"City":"Agawam","DMA":"SPRINGFIELD, MA"},...
```

My question is the following.  Shouldn't there be an array name preceding the Json array? For example:

```
{"zones":[{"Zip_Code":...
```

When I parse this using Jquery I need to use something along the lines of $.each(json.zones so I'm wondering how to include the array name in the Jason response.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
return Json(new { zones = zones }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: Yes it did.  I just finished testing it.  Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

This example from [json.org](http://json.org/example.html) may help clarify...

```
{"menu": {
  "id": "file",
  "value": "File",
  "popup": {
    "menuitem": [
      {"value": "New", "onclick": "CreateNewDoc()"},
      {"value": "Open", "onclick": "OpenDoc()"},
      {"value": "Close", "onclick": "CloseDoc()"}
    ]
  }
}}
```

Using this example as a starting point, I would say you would do this (imagining the zones were different!):

```
{"zones": [
      {"Zip-Code": "1001", "City": "Agawam", "DMA": "SPRINGFIELD, MA"},
      {"Zip-Code": "1001", "City": "Agawam", "DMA": "SPRINGFIELD, MA"},
      {"Zip-Code": "1001", "City": "Agawam", "DMA": "SPRINGFIELD, MA"}
    ]
}
```

Comment: Zones is the collection.  In the example, Agawam represents a single zone in the array.

Answer (score 0):

```
 JSONObject title = new JSONObject();
 JSONObject main = new JSONObject();

title.put("zone", main);
main.put("Zip Code", value);
main.put("City", value);
........
```